# Converting seconds to MM:HH:SS in Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to convert seconds to the format: `HH::MM:SS`

Here is my code:

`Session Duration` is the metric in seconds, I have derived 3 fields from it as shown below:

Session_Hours: `MOD(Sum(Session Duration),3600)`
Session_Minutes: `MOD(Sum(Session Duration) - Session_Hours*3600,60)`
Session_Seconds: `Sum(Session_Duration) - Session_Hours*3600 - Session_Minutes*60`

But when I try to format it into: `hh:mm:ss` using:

`CONCAT(CAST(Session_Hours as String),CONCAT(":",CONCAT(CAST(Session_Minutes as String),CONCAT(":",CAST(Session_Seconds as String)))))`

It throws me following error:

- Metric expressions and aggregations are not allowed in this expression.

Does anyone know how to do this or a better way of converting seconds to `HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set the `Session Duration` field in Google Analytics to an `HH:MM:SS` field, set the Field Type to `Duration (Sec.)`; the aggregation can then be set as required, such as [AVG](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583518).

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/04bf889f-439c-468c-bc9f-1ee421e46aa1) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]